# Parallax Effect Issue While Scrolling

Tags: html, css, parallax

I want an image to fit a container element but my code is only showing half of the image, without the desired parallax effect. Can anyone explain why it isn't displaying the full image?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.top_nav {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  position: absolute;
}
.container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url("http://cdn.pcwallart.com/images/beautiful-nature-animals-wallpaper-3.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -1;
}
.details {
  height: 638px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #00e5de;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="top_nav">

  </div>
</header>
<div class="container">
  <div id="short-des">

  </div>
</div>
<div class=details>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: You have given `400px` height to `.container` that's why its showing half image

Comment: but i also made image position to be center so why its not align on center ?

Comment: Just because you have given `background-size: cover;` so its covering the entire element's background, e.g., use custom size for bg-image (let say 100px) and you will see your image is centered aligned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `100vh` for your `.container` height

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.top_nav {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  position: absolute;
}
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url("http://cdn.pcwallart.com/images/beautiful-nature-animals-wallpaper-3.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -1;
}
.details {
  height: 638px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #00e5de;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="top_nav">

  </div>
</header>
<div class="container">
  <div id="short-des">

  </div>
</div>
<div class=details>
</div>
```

vh: hundredths of the viewport height.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is expand the height of the container. You can use the vh sizing unit (hundredths of viewport height) or any other unit.